# How to join 7 tables in SQL using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure to join 7 tables in SQL using INNER JOIN, however I am getting an error about incorrect syntax.

I've tried to adjust formatting but I cannot get the syntax correct. Does anyone know where I've gone wrong? I get an error stating

> Incorrect syntax near "WHERE"

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInvoicing]
    @InvoiceId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        tblInvoices.InvoiceId, tblInvoices.InvoiceDate, 
        tblClients.Firstname, tblClients.Surname, tblClients.Address, tblClients.City, 
        tblClients.Postcode, tblClients.Email, tblClients.Phone, 
        tblAppointments.AppointmentId, tblAppointments.DateOfAppointment, 
        tblProductsUsed.ProductsUsedId, tblProducts.ProductName, tblProductsUsed.Quantity, 
        tblPointofSale.SaleId, tblPointOfSale.CostOfProducts, tblPointOfSale.CostOfServices, 
        tblPointOfSale.VAT, tblInvoices.SaleAmount, tblInvoices.PaymentMethod 
    FROM
        tblClients 
    INNER JOIN
        tblAppointments ON tblClients.ClientId = tblAppointments.ClientId  
    INNER JOIN
        tblPointOfSale 
    INNER JOIN
        tblInvoices ON tblPointOfSale.SaleId = tblInvoices.SaleId 
    INNER JOIN
        tblProductsUsed 
    INNER JOIN
        tblProducts ON tblProductsUsed.ProductId = tblProducts.ProductId 
    INNER JOIN
        tblServicesRendered 
    INNER JOIN 
        tblServices ON tblServicesRendered.ServiceId = tblServices.ServiceId ON tblServicesRendered.AppointmentId =  tblAppointments.AppointmentId 
        ON tblPointOfSale.AppointmentId = tblAppointments.AppointmentId 
        AND tblProductsUsed.SaleId = tblPointOfSale.SaleId 
        AND tblPointOfSale.ClientId = tblClients.ClientId
    WHERE 
        tblInvoices.InvoiceId = @InvoiceId
END
```

Comment: So, your question is purely about SQL syntax yet you tag it VB.NET but not SQL? Please use sensible and relevant tags.

Comment: You need to use `ON` IMMEDIATELY after each `INNER JOIN`. You can't have all those `ON` clauses at the end. You need `table INNER JOIN table ON column = column INNER JOIN table ON column = column...` like that. If you need to change the order of your tables in the SQL to be able to do that then do so. If you need to use parentheses to group some joins into a result that can then be joined with another table/result then do that.

Answer (score 3):

Your JOINs got a bit scrambled.  Try this below, and see if that fixes the syntax error.

Always try to get your JOINs to follow the format `INNER JOIN [Table2] ON [Table2].[Field1] = [Table1].[Field1]`

```
FROM tblClients
    INNER JOIN tblAppointments ON tblClients.ClientId = tblAppointments.ClientId
    INNER JOIN tblPointOfSale ON tblPointOfSale.AppointmentId = tblAppointments.AppointmentId
        AND tblPointOfSale.ClientId = tblClients.ClientId
    INNER JOIN tblInvoices ON tblPointOfSale.SaleId = tblInvoices.SaleId 
    INNER JOIN tblProductsUsed ON tblProductsUsed.SaleId = tblPointOfSale.SaleId
    INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblProductsUsed.ProductId = tblProducts.ProductId 
    INNER JOIN tblServicesRendered ON tblServicesRendered.AppointmentId =  tblAppointments.AppointmentId
    INNER JOIN tblServices ON tblServicesRendered.ServiceId = tblServices.ServiceId
```

Answer (score 1):

I just copy and pasted your code into this website - http://poorsql.com/
and it hightlighted the error for you (you're missing AND in the joins). 
As @DBro said - get in the habit of putting your JOINs on the new line and format it a little differently, and you'll have far less trouble.